# Sign a message with a cold wallet private key and then verifying it with their monero address

Tags: bitcoin, messagesigning

I'm looking to setup a monero address for each of my users on my website so they can sign a message to prove that they own the monero address. Since you cannot sign a message with your payment_id, this is the only way it seems. My main concern is if a user can prove that they own that specific address, by signing the a message.

A good example is by signing the message of a bitcoin address, it proves that the monero user owns that particular bitcoin address. This is just one of the use cases I have.

Comment: Is there a question ?

Comment: Hi @duckx, You also asked about signing messages here: [How to sign a message with my public monero address and verify it using the cli / gui / javascript app?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/how-to-sign-a-message-with-my-public-monero-address-and-verify-it-using-the-cli) and got very detailed answers, but did not select one.  What is different here?

Comment: It's different. Say I have 100 users and each users has their own private key on their account. I want to be able to write a script where I can just sign a message with their private key without the need to import their key into the wallet or best not even needing the core wallet if possible.

Comment: You need the private key to sign a message, same in Bitcoin and Monero.  I don't see any way that you could use the key to sign a message without importing it into some piece of software.